# How do I update my view after the user allows location use

Tags: ios, asynchronous, model-view-controller, location

I'm sure there's a generic approach to this but I cannot figure out the search terms.

I have a settings view controller which includes a table view and in one cell a switch to turn on location use. When the user toggles that switch I fire a view controller method to take the necessary action.

If they turn the switch OFF, then I tell my model to store that choice in my NSUserDefaults and update the view to reflect this (including removing some table cells). No problems here.

If they turn the switch ON (for the first time), my method fires and completes before the user can allow location use in the system pop-up. Thus the view is not being updated. Which is technically correct, but a bad user experience as the UI does not update to reflect their change.

I'm handling the change of location tracking state in the model, which is the location delegate, so if the settings view is dismissed and re-opened all is as it should be.

My question is how do I asynchronously tell my view to update, assuming it is still displayed. It seems physically certain it will still be on screen unless the user is superhuman, though logically it need not be.

UPDATE: Adding some code snippets to better illustrate.

Here are the key parts of my model class which both stores my own state of location tracking (the useLocation variable) and acts as the location manager delegate:

```
public class WorldModel : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var useLocation = false

    override init() {

        super.init()
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        useLocation = userDefaults.boolForKey("useLocation")
        let locationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        switch locationStatus {
        case .NotDetermined:
            useLocation = false
        case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            break
        case .Denied, .Restricted:
            useLocation = false
            userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "useLocation")
        }
        if useLocation {
            setLocationTracking(true)
        }
    }

    // ================================================================================
    // Turn on or off location tracking for the model
    // ================================================================================
    public func setLocationAllowed(allowed: Bool) {
        useLocation = allowed
        setLocationTracking(allowed)
    }

    // ================================================================================
    // Turn on or off location tracking with the OS
    // ================================================================================
    public func setLocationTracking(state: Bool) {
        if state {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    // ================================================================================
    // Capture location permission changes from the OS
    // ================================================================================
    public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        switch status {
        case .NotDetermined:
            useLocation = false
        case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            useLocation = true
            userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "useLocation")
        case .Denied, .Restricted:
            useLocation = false
            userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "useLocation")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the view controller which is managing the settings view I want to update. (Relevant parts only again.)

```
class SettingsViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var theWorldModel : WorldModel?

    func allowLocationChange(sender: UISwitch) {
        guard let ourWorld = theWorldModel else {
            return
        }
        ourWorld.setLocationAllowed(sender.on)
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

The allowLocationChange method is fired by the switch on the screen and in the case of turning off it has immediate effect because I am taking the "switch off" concept directly to my model. In the case of "switch on" I still go to my model to effect it, but the result is not immediate (due to the OS popping up the request) and so the setNeedsDisplay is setting up the display before the model has registered the change.

Theoretically I could block in the allowLocationChange method but that just sounds like a bad idea on so many levels.

Comment: Only description not enough to understand put some code and visual flow @zkarj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CLLocationManager class, which is the root class for location feature in iOS.

[CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/)

I'd offer you to develop your own class, which would be responsible for working with CLLocationManager instance for your application.
It would have hidden instance of CLLocationManager, a list of methods to work with that instance (like currentAuthorizationStatus(), authorise()...), and what is more important this class would be assigned as a delegate for CLLocationManager instance.

One of CLLocationManagerDelegate Protocol methods is 
[locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:). In implementation of this method you can post notification through NSNoticationCenter. And your Settings viewController should be subscribed to this notification and react correspondingly.

It's up to you how to keep your class instance alive and unique in your application. I use singleton pattern.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see from the code I added, I was already capturing the change, but didn't understand how to pass it to the view I thought it had to be something like that or I was missing something obvious.

I've now got the notification arriving into my view controller and just need to get it to perform the updates correctly.